# Order by case and number

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, case

This is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM `players` 
WHERE `team` = '$team' 
ORDER BY `spot` ASC, 
CASE WHEN 
`spot` LIKE '%LW%' THEN '1' 
WHEN `spot` LIKE '%C%' THEN '2' 
WHEN `spot` LIKE '%RW%' THEN '3' 
END
```

My goal is to order it by:

- 1LW
- 1C
- 1RW
- 2LW
- 2C
- 2RW

I am struggling to figure out how to achieve this. Here is what my table looks like:
[image: table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT * FROM `players` 
WHERE `team` = '$team' 
ORDER BY cast(spot as unsigned),
CASE WHEN 
`spot` LIKE '%LW%' THEN '1' 
WHEN `spot` LIKE '%C%' THEN '2' 
WHEN `spot` LIKE '%RW%' THEN '3' 
END
```